# How do I configure my Linksys WRT160N to be a wireless access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, wireless-access-point, internet-connection

I'm trying to set up a [Linksys WRT160N](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT160N/) wireless router as an access point in order to extend the effective range of a working Belkin wireless router that has internet access.

I don't know the model of the Belkin router, but  is what the router access screen looks like @ 192.168.2.1:[image]

The wifi is unsecured and is giving out IP addresses. The DHCP range is 192.168.2.2 through 192.168.2.100.  There is no time limit on the lease either.

I've tried a couple of setups on the WRT160N but could'n get any configurations to make the Linksys behanve as a wireless access point.

The most reasonable configuration, in my opinion, was to give the WRT160 a fixed IP of 192.168.2.99, turn the DHCP of the wireless access point off, and use 192.168.2.1 (Belkin WiFi) as the gateway & dns servers.

I have a similar set up in my house where I set up a wireless router with static IP and DHCP disabled to act as an access point.  It obtained the "internet" through one of the 4 wired ethernet jacks on both routers and not via WiFi.  That's the only difference, I suppose.  I need the internet "feed" to be obtained wirelessly rather than through a wired connection.

What am I missing?

I have been reading manuals and Q&A sites about the issue but could not find the right help.

---

**EDIT:**

---

I don't have access to any piece of hardware except for the Linksys WRT160N.  The other pieces I am trying to connect to/bridge with are in an inaccessible area.  I cant run wires to or from them, I can only connect to the router via a browser wirelessly.

Comment: What you need is a wireless range extender (repeater), not a wireless router. I'm doubtful that the model you have can act as a repeater, but it might. You'll need to dig into the documentation to see.

Comment: @joeqwerty with DD-WRT, it can function as a repeater (I used the same router to do just this).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you can just take it back to the store and get an access point.

That being said, all you should have to do here is disable DHCP on the WRT160 and give the device a static IP address in the same subnet. If it want's a default route it should be the IP of your other router. You should have a cable from one of the LAN ports of your existing wireless router to one of the LAN ports on the WRT160. The WRT160 should then simply act as an access point, layer 3 connectivity will be serviced by the other router.

Alternatively, you could change the IP scheme of this new access point to something like 192.168.3.x/24 and connect the WAN port to the existing router and you'd also be done. Lots of options.

I just noticed your comment regarding the need for this to be a wireless extender/bridge. Read the manual or run a cable.

Comment: and my quick look at the owners manual shows no wireless bridging/extending options in the wireless setup. I use Apple airport express devices to do this in consumer applications.

Comment: The WRT160N is actually four different routers (with two *very* different designs). Can you check your actual version? (1.0, 1.1, 2.0, or 3.0)  Also, can you clarify how you're trying to use it? (Will it be connected by wires or wireless to the existing access point? Will it have local wired devices connected to it or just be a wireless repeater?)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Linksys wrt160 V2 router and I set it up as an access point by running an ethernet cable from my main Belkin router which is directly connected to my Motorola modem into one of the four blue ethernet out ports. I disabled the DHCP Server and changed Internet Connection Type to Static IP under Setup/Basic in the router menu. That is all I did to make it work. See the attached image for settings...

Sorry I wasn't allowed to add an image which would have have been very helpful.

Comment: thanks for the info, but i guess i wasn't specific enough in my question... read edit

Answer (score 0):

For everyone finding this in Google, here's how to make a WRT160N work as an access point, straight from Linksys themselves: https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=135179

Those are good clear instructions that worked for my unit (v1 or 1.1), but in case they disappear, the steps are:

1. Physically connect your computer to one of the router's numbered ports, (not the 'internet' port). [Note: I don't know why they recommend this, I bet you could do this process over wifi no problem.]
2. Log into the router (default 192.168.1.1 un: pw:admin)
3. Administration > Upnp > Disabled > Save Settings
4. Setup >
   a. Internet Connection Type > Automatic Configuration - DHCP
   b. Router IP > IP Address > pick something not in use, e.g. 192.168.1.2
   c. DHCP Server Setting > DHCP Server > Disabled
   d. Save Settings

Done. (and you're not supposed to use the yellow/internet port anymore).
Don't forget to configure the wifi's ssid, and security.

I know this doesn't answer OP's question of: 'How do I extend my neighbor's open wifi to cover my house?', but instead this solves the question in the post's title.  This post currently has over 41k views, that's a lot of old hardware looking for a second life!

Answer (score 0):

**CheeseConQueso As PER  YOUR QUESTION :-**

I'm trying to set up a Linksys WRT160N wireless router as an access point in order to **extend the effective range** of a working Belkin wireless router that has internet access.

It means you  want **to use it as an EXTENDER/REPEATOR** ...If **i am not wrong** you want to catch **Belkin WiFi  signals and extend** it to other rooms.

As **practically tested** wireless extension or repeaters  are not successful if ones signals  break due to interference of any mobile hotspot or other device  frequency  radio or channel signals or  lower down of signals of first router **(Belkin WiFi signals)**  will effect the other to  broadcast so for stability it is always preferred to  connect through the a Lan cable which connects  Belkin Wifi to Linksys Router and then Extend or broadcast it else it will **give problems and unstable** .

**Still if you want then now how to  configure it as an wireless extender repeater** as this model is OLD and archived model and is a router and to configure it as an Access point or repeater this model dont have features in its its setup when I searched in google  and linksys found many problems with this model regarding making it an AP  that to  make it work as repeater or AP there are **3rd party  firmware available** through which   many make it work **as  you have replied** in comment that you have used this model in your house then the **version or model** must be different or  **firmware must be Old or new**  one cross check it  then  if its possible then copy

Still many users have tricks or solutions without and with changing of firmware which i am sharing  links below is the **links and videos details** to how to configure  and  **i am sharing with you** below it may help you. Which one will work and good  its you have try and test in case of your model version and firmware version see which works for you .

**According to reference linksys website link says :-**

https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=136155

For pictures and details see the link

> **Configuring the Wireless Repeater mode on most Linksys Smart Wi-Fi Routers**
>
> **Some Linksys Smart Wi-Fi Routers support Wireless Repeater mode.  To check if your router has this option, log in to the router's web-based setup page and click on Connectivity > Internet Setting**
>
> Step 1:
>   Enter “http://192.168.1.1” in your web browser’s Address bar and log in to your Linksys Smart Wi-Fi router.
>
> QUICK TIP:  The default IP Address of the Linksys router is 192.168.1.1.  If you have modified it, use the new IP Address instead.
>
> Step 2:
>   Click Connectivity.
>
> Step 3:
>   Click Internet Settings.
>
> Step 4:
>   Click Edit.
>
> Step 5:
>   Select Wireless Repeater.
>
> Step 6:
>   Enter the main router or access point’s Network name (SSID), Network band and Security mode.
>
> Step 7:
>   Click  to save settings.  Click Yes to continue.

**According to reference linksys Community website link User Expert GV solution  says :-**

https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/Can-a-WRT160N-V3-be-used-as-a-wireless-access-point/m-p/317716#M167181

> 1. Yes, you can use your second WRT and set it up as second access point for your network.
> 2. First, unplug the second WRT from your network and wire a computer into one of its LAN ports.
> 3. Open the web interface at http://192.168.1.1/ On the main setup page, change the LAN IP address from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.2
> 4. disable the DHCP server. Save settings.
> 5. Unplug the computer and connect the cable from the first router into one of the LAN ports of the second router.
> 6. Do not use the internet port of the second router! Now you can use the wireless access point in the second router as additional access point to your network.
> 7. For a wireless roaming network set both WRTs with identical wireless settings (i.e. SSID, wireless security, etc.) and make sure to enable SSID broadcast.
> 8. Only channel assignments should be different. Use different channels at least 5 apart to avoid overlapping channels. Now your laptop can connect to your network through either WRT and has internet through the first WRT.
> 9. It should also be able to move between both WRTs without loosing the connection.
> 10. As the WRT160N only has 10/100 ethernet ports a CAT5e should do. Of course, you may consider getting a better cable, e.g. a cat6 for future improvements of your network. It depends on how much effort it takes to replace the cable later if you decide to go for gigabit ethernet in your LAN.

**According to reference linksys Community website link User Expert GV another remark  says :-**

https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/Can-a-WRT160N-V3-be-used-as-a-wireless-access-point/m-p/317716#M167181

> 1. Yes. 3rd party firmware will allow you to reconfigure the WRT as wireless bridge.
> 2. I won't comment on the quality of the response of the technical support.
> 3. Linksys WAP devices like the WAP54G used to be versatile wireless access points which could be reconfigured as bridge or repeater using Linksys firmware.
> 4. The WAP610N, however, specifically cannot be configured as bridge or repeater. The WAP610N is only a wireless access point. It won't operate as wireless bridge or repeater as previous WAPs did.
> 5. If you still know the name of the support person you could call again and complain. Refer them to the user guide available online. It clearly shows the configuration options. Setting the WAP610N to bridge is not an option as it used to be in the WAP54G.
> 6. In my opinion, running a wire is always the better solution. Always. Reliable, steady streaming even if your neighbor decides to do some heavy downloading on his wireless routers using the same channel as yours... And it leaves you more bandwidth with your other wireless devices...

More links for firmware update and same issues  are  as below you can see and read  and may found some solutions which work for you

https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r22483979-Repeater-with-WRT160N

https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r22038551-Re-DDWRT-Detailed-instructions-on-bridging-router

https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/Using-WRT54G-as-second-wireless-with-E2500/m-p/804688#M273630

https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=110181

https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=300498

https://itstillworks.com/set-linksys-router-wireless-repeater-6848173.html

https://www.wikihow.com/Configure-a-Linksys-WRT160N-Router

3rd party new firmware links

https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/?model=WRT160N_1.0/1.1

Videos links 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aLAOZpf2w4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R3ktjazLMA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJaYE9Yk7gc

> if any of my answer works and suits your problem then do tell me in comments for my knowledge and research which one worked for you and if not then feel free to ask further clarification queries regarding the answer in comments . If worked then dont forget to vote for my answers and accept the answer.